# How to dynamically change the anchor tag link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remove a landing page when I click on a link on a page. The page isn't mine so I'm trying to change the href with a user script.

Without any modification, the link looks like this:

```
https://www.domain.com/out.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DPUZ1bC-1XjA%26amp%3Bfeature%3Drelated
```

What I want:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUZ1bC-1XjA&feature=related
```

What I got so far:

```
http://www.youtube.com%2fwatch%3fv%3dpuz1bc-1xja%26amp%3bfeature%3drelated/
```

But that adress doesn't work in the browser.

This is my current code:

```
$('a').each(function(index) {
            var aLink = $(this).attr('href');
            if(aLink) {
                if(aLink.indexOf("out.php?u=") > 0) {
                    aLink = aLink.substring(51);
                    console.log(aLink);
                    $(this).attr('href', "http://"+aLink);
                    console.log($(this).prop('href'));
                }

            }
        });
```

All help and tips are appreciated.

Comment: you should use a url parser like [`parseUri`](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/parseuri) rather than using string functions to parse it yourself: `parseUri(aLink).queryKey.u`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `decode` the URL using `decodeURIComponent`

Change:

```
$(this).attr('href', "http://"+aLink);
```

To:

```
$(this).attr('href', 'http://' + decodeURIComponent(aLink));
```

Comment: I would think he'd want to change var aLink = $(this).attr('href');
 instead

Comment: @Jason: Why do that `extra` decoding when there is no `out.php?u=` found in the link?

Comment: Ah, true.  I hadn't paid close enough attention.  It was more of a "do you de/encoding at the top of the block" axiom, but in this case it does result in superfluous calls.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

Comment: Thanks for answering but the answer with examples will get the "Accepted answer".

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of the `hostname`, `pathname`, and `search` parameters of anchor elements.

```
// general function to turn query strings into objects
function deserialize_query_string(qs) {
    var params = {};
    var fields = qs.split('&');
    var field;
    for (var i=0; i<fields.length; i++) {
        field = fields[i].split('=');
        field[0] = decodeURIComponent(field[0]);
        field[1] = decodeURIComponent(field[1]);
        params[field[0]] = field[1];
    }
    return params;
}

$(document.links).each(function(i){
    if (this.hostname=='www.domain.com' && this.pathname=='/out.php') {
        var params = deserialize_query_string(this.search);
        if (params.u) {
            this.href = u;
        }
    }
});
```